# Spark - do transformations also involve driver operations

Tags: apache-spark

My course notes have the following sentence: "RDDs support two types of operations: transformations, which create a new dataset from an existing one, and actions, which return a value to the driver program after running a computation on the dataset." But I think this is misleading because the transformation **reduceByKey** is performed locally on the workers and then on the driver as well (although the change does not take place until there's an action to be performed). Could you please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: saveAsTextFile is also an Action. That does not mean returning a value to the Driver.

Comment: @thebluephantom that’s correct the action whether return results to the driver or save the result to a storage system

Comment: Yes I know, was commenting on the prose in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the concepts

In Spark Transformation defines where one RDD generates one or more RDD. Everytime a new RDD is created. RDDs are immutable so any transformation on one RDD generates a new RDD and its added to DAG.

Action in spark are the function where new RDDs are not generated its generated other datatypes like String, int etc.. and result is returned to driver or other storage system.

Transformations are lazy in nature and nothing happen until action is triggered.

reduceByKey - Its a transformation as it generates a RDD from input RDD and its a WIDE TRANFORMATION. In reduce by key nothing happens until action is triggered. Please see the image below

[image]

reduce - its an action as it generates a non RDD type. Please see the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, driver's first responsibility is managing the job. Moreover, RDD's objects are not located on driver to have an action on them. So, all the results are on workers till the actions' turns come. The thing which I mean is about lazy execution of spark, it means at first of the execution the plan is reviewed to the first action and if it could not find any then the whole program would result nothing. Otherwise, whole the program will be executed on the input data which would be presented as rdd object on the worker nodes to reach the action and all the data during this period would all be on workers and just the result according to the type of the action would be sent to or at least managed by the driver.